# DevExpress TreeList settingSelection recursive

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

**ASPX**

```
<dx:ASPxTreeList ID="ASPxTreeListLocations" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceUserMetersTree" KeyFieldName="sno" ParentFieldName="ParentId"
    Width="300px" SettingsSelection-Recursive="true" Theme="Office2010Black">
    <Columns>
        <dx:TreeListTextColumn FieldName="Text" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Lokasyon">
        </dx:TreeListTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <SettingsBehavior AutoExpandAllNodes="True" />
    <SettingsSelection Enabled="True" />
</dx:ASPxTreeList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceUserMetersTree" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**CODEBEHID**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSourceUserMetersTree.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Tree";
    ASPxTreeListLocations.DataBind();
}
```

**QUESTION:**

Codes are working well. I want to recursive selection, but this property is not working. If I define SqlDataSource selectCommand in aspx side, it works. I cant find any solution. No error message. Any advice?

Thanks...

Comment: Is ASPxTreeList populated with data when you define selectcommand in code behind?

Comment: Yes. Data is expected. I can retrive and change data. All about treeList are working.

Comment: Check this [link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4231).

Comment: You could write your comment as answer. I will accept that.

Comment: Check this link: [How to: Enable Recursive Selection When Binding at Runtime](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4231)

Comment: I Move my code without changing to the Page_Init method. It woked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the option `recursive = "true"` to your tree settings, 
NP